# Apache Sling Job distribution

Tags: osgi, sling

I need some advice. I have to choose between sling events or jobs.
In documentation it is precisely said that events are distributed to all nodes in cluster, so I could handle it in each one separately and thats ok.

But it's stated jobs are more reliable and that's what I want to achieve - reliability. 
But there's a catch: job can only be executed in one job consumer.
Is there some similar mechanism as with events I mean if I could consume job in each cluster node and notify sender about success/failure on each node?